# Critical points : $ z = \cos^2x + \cos^2y$ for $ y-x = \frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find and classify the critic points (maximum, minimum or neither) of the function $$z=z(x,y) = \cos^2x + \cos^2y $$

if $y-x = \large\frac{\pi}{4}$

I've find $x = -\large\frac{\pi}{8} + \large\frac{k \pi}{2}$ and $y = \large\frac{\pi}{8} + \large\frac{k \pi}{2}$ ($k \in \Bbb{Z}$), but I sm having troubles to classify the points.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

use
$$\cos^2{x}+\cos^2{y}=\dfrac{1}{2}(\cos{(2x)}+\cos{(2y)})+1=\cos{(x+y)}\cos{(x-y)}+1=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos{(x+y)}+1$$

since
$$y=x+\dfrac{\pi}{4}$$
so
$$\cos^2{x}+\cos^2{y}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos{(2x+\dfrac{\pi}{4})}+1\in[1-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2},1+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}]$$
if only if $2x+\dfrac{\pi}{4}=2k\pi$ and $2x+\dfrac{\pi}{4}=(2k-1)\pi$

Comment: I did this, but as I said, I know the point but i am having trouble to clasify it (using the signal of the second derivative when the problem is reduced to 1 variable)

Answer (score 1):

Use $$\cos^2x+\cos^2y=\frac{1+\cos2x+1+\cos2y}2=1+\frac{\cos2x+\cos2\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)}2$$
$$=1+\frac{\cos2x-\sin2x}2$$  as $\cos\left(\frac\pi2+y\right)=-\sin y$

So, the problem reduces to single variable

Comment: thanks for you answer. As I said, I've already find the critical points (reducing to 1 variable). But, I am trying look for the second derivative of the function (of one variable) and I this is not helping me to classify the point (they are local minimum)

Comment: @Giiovanna,Please use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html